# What is my HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject Method Virtual Path?

Tags: asp.net

I have read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149953.aspx and need to verify what is my `GetLocalResourceObject` virtual path.

My local resource files are located on my pc at:

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\GlobalX\Input\App_LocalResources

Within this folder are my resource files for all the languages that site handles (InputContactDetails.aspx.ro.resx,  InputContactDetails.aspx.hi.resx, etc.), as well as the default resource file (InputContactDetails.aspx.resx).

I am receiving an error when I attempt to implement the virtual path string. Below is my line of offending code:

```
return '<%= HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/GlobalX/Input/App_LocalResources/InputContactDetails.aspx.resx", "ContactDetails.Text", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ro")) %>';
```

I have tried `~/GlobalX/Input/App_LocalResources` as the virtual path, and several other permutations, but I get the same error.

If someone could show what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate it greatly.

Here is the error message I am getting:

> The resource class for this page was not found. Please check if the
>   resource file exists and try again.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The resource
>   class for this page was not found. Please check if the resource file
>   exists and try again.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 410:     function languageContactPromptPhone(var_lcs) { Line
>   411:          if (var_lcs == "af") { Line 412: return '<%=
>   HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/GlobalX/Input/App_LocalResources/InputContactDetails.aspx.resx",
>   "ContactDetails.Text", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ro"))
>   %>'; Line 413:            } Line 414:         else if (var_lcs == "sq") {
>
> Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\GlobalX\Input\InputContactDetails.aspx
>   Line: 412
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The resource class for this page was not
>   found.  Please check if the resource file exists and try again.]
>   System.Web.Compilation.LocalResXResourceProvider.CreateResourceManager()
>   +2785818    System.Web.Compilation.BaseResXResourceProvider.EnsureResourceManager()
>   +24    System.Web.Compilation.BaseResXResourceProvider.GetObject(String
>   resourceKey, CultureInfo culture) +15
>   System.Web.Compilation.ResourceExpressionBuilder.GetResourceObject(IResourceProvider
>   resourceProvider, String resourceKey, CultureInfo culture, Type
>   objType, String propName) +23
>   System.Web.HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(String virtualPath,
>   String resourceKey, CultureInfo culture) +38
>   ASP.input_inputcontactdetails_aspx.__RenderContentInputContactDetails(HtmlTextWriter
>   __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\GlobalX\Input\InputContactDetails.aspx:412
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) +109
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +8
>   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +27
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +8991378
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) +208
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +8
>   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +27
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +8991378
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) +208
>   System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +256
>   System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +37
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +27
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +8991378
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
>   ASP.masterpages_masterinput_master.__RenderformMasterInput(HtmlTextWriter
>   __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\GlobalX\MasterPages\MasterInput.master:140
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) +109
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +173
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +31
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +53 
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +27
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +8991378
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +40
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) +208
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +8
>   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +27
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +8991378
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) +208
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +8
>   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +29
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +27
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +8991378
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3060

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use /GlobalX/Input/App_LocalResources/InputContactDetails.aspx.resx, remove ~

Answer (score 3):

Had the same error in Asp.Net 4.6 in Code-Behind. It was caused by having *App_LocalResources* in the Path.

```
HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/App_LocalResources/Default.aspx", "SampleResource.Text")
```

Resulted in error:
The resource class for this page was not found. Please check if the resource file exists and try again.

Without */App_LocalResources* it works:

```
HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/Default.aspx", "SampleResource.Text")
```